Type with unbounded SU-rank has a forking extension with unbounded SU-rank
I'm reading Kim's Simplicity Theory, specifically Lemma 2.5.15 which states that for a complete type $p(x) \in S(A)$, the following are equivalent: (a) $\operatorname{SU}(p) = \infty$, (b) for some $B \supseteq A$, $p$ has a forking extension $q \in S(B)$ with $\operatorname{SU}(q) = \infty$, and (c) there is a forking chain $(p_i : i \in \omega)$ with $p_0 = p$.
I'm having a bit of trouble proving (a) $\implies$ (b) without assuming the ambient theory $T$ is simple. By (a), for each ordinal $\alpha$, there is $A_\alpha \supseteq A$ and $p_\alpha \in S(A_\alpha)$ which forks over $p$ and for which $\operatorname{SU}(p_\alpha) \geq \alpha$. Following an earlier proof in Kim, I was trying to do a pigeonhole argument, but I'm not sure why/if we can assume only boundedly many types $p_\alpha$ in this case.
I know there is a proof in Casanovas using the fact that there is an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\operatorname{SU}(p) \geq \alpha$ implies $\operatorname{SU}(p) = \infty$, but this proof relies on the local character of forking in simple theories. Is simplicity of $T$ necessary to prove (a) $\implies$ (b), or the upper bound on possible $\operatorname{SU}$-ranks of types?

Suppose $p\in S(A)$ and $\DeclareMathOperator{\SU}{SU}\DeclareMathOperator{\tp}{tp} \SU(p) = \infty$. For each ordinal $\alpha$, pick $p_\alpha\in S(A_\alpha)$ with $A\subseteq A_\alpha$ such that $p_\alpha$ is a forking extension of $p$, and $\SU(p_\alpha)\geq \alpha$.
Since $p_\alpha$ forks over $A$, there is some formula $\varphi_\alpha(x,b_\alpha)\in p_\alpha$ which forks over $A$. Let $B_\alpha = A\cup \{b_\alpha\}$, and let $q_\alpha = p_\alpha|_{B_\alpha}$. Since $q_\alpha\subseteq p_\alpha$, $\SU(q_\alpha)\geq \SU(p_\alpha)\geq \alpha$. Note also that $q_\alpha$ is a forking extension of $p$, since $\varphi_\alpha(x,b_\alpha)\in q_\alpha$.
Now we argue that there is an upper bound on the ordinals appearing as $\SU(q_\alpha)$. Here's one way to do that: Let $M$ be an $|A|^+$-saturated model containing $A$. For each $\alpha$, let $b_\alpha^*\in M$ realize $\tp(b_\alpha/A)$, and let $B_\alpha^* = A\cup \{b_\alpha^*\}$. Then the obvious elementary map $B_\alpha \to B_\alpha^*$ moves $q_\alpha\in S(B_\alpha)$ to $q_\alpha^*\in S(B_\alpha^*)$, which is still a forking extension of $p$ and has the same $\SU$-rank as $q_\alpha$. But since there are a bounded number of complete types over subsets of $M$, there is an upper bound $\beta$ on the ordinals appearing as $\SU(q_\alpha^*)$.
Since $\SU(q_{\beta+1}^*) \geq \beta+1>\beta$, it follows that $\SU(q_{\beta+1}^*) = \infty$. So we have found a forking extension of $p$ with $\SU$-rank $\infty$, as desired.

Note that this argument does not show that there is an upper bound on the ordinals appearing as $\SU(q)$ where $q$ ranges over arbitrary forking extensions of $p$, just that if $\SU(q)$ is large enough, then some restriction of $q$ to a small set witnessing forking has $\SU$-rank infinity.
I don't know whether an upper bound on the possible ordinal $\SU$-ranks of types exists in general. It's a great question!

Thanks Alex! I think that makes sense to me.
